# Suggestions on naming convention for Branches

Tags: git, configuration, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

We have two separate artifacts in Visual Studio Team foundation Server, one for Source code (branch) and another for Database scripts (folder).

branches are - 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 ... to 3-mainline, and we also have 4-mainline.

actually 4-mainline (4.0) is already released, while we are also working on 3.9 (yet to be released). there are folders - 3.0_to_3.1, 3.7_to_3.8, 4.0 etc for database scripts,

the problem is, suppose we implement a feature (for 3.9 which requires Database changes) but he feature is not for 4.0 (as 4.0 is already released). so while upgrading DB from lower version to 4.0, the scripts for 3.9 will also be executed (which should not be).

Can you please suggest me a naming convention or any relevant solution in this regard.

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a script in 4.0 which would revert Database changes introduced by the script in 3.9 (new feature).

That way, I don't have to deal with naming convention: I execute sequentially those scripts, and the end result is "no database changes" for 4.0.